# Excel VBA - How to convert string to formula when creating a named range

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing some code to create a lot of identical sheets, based on a master sheet.  The master sheet has quite a few named ranges, which I need to duplicate across to the new sheets (each named range name has a numbered prefix appropriate to the name of the sheet, e.g. P1_rngname, P2_rngname etc). I am currently building the new name and the new range as strings based on the data from the master sheet, with the important lines of code below:

```
Form = "='P" & Pnum & "'!" & Range(Pmaster_nm).Address
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="P" & Pnum & nm, RefersToR1C1:=Form
```

Pnum is the new sheet name prefix for the named range
nm is the suffix for the new named range (same as suffix for master)
so that "P" & Pnum & nm is the name of the new named range
Pmaster_nm is the named range name in the master sheet being copied

Form is the new range on the new sheet e.g. `"='P5'!$G$8"` (the variable is defined as a string)

However, when I run the code, I get a run-time error 1004 "there's a problem with this formula" when it hits the line to add the new name.  I suspect it is because the ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add is expecting a range but is getting a string.  I have tried defining Form as a range but then the error occurs on the earlier line.  How can I get it to think that Form is a formula?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If `Pmaster_nm` is the name of the named range, rather than a variable representing it, it needs to be in quotes.

Comment: For stafters, *Form* is not being constructed as an xlR1C1 address. Maybe try `Range(Pmaster_nm).Address(true, true, xlR1C1)`.

Comment: Or remove the R1C1 from the refersto.

Comment: Thank you!  Pmaster_nm is a variable containing the named range name, but your pointer on the R1C1 was spot on!  I changed it to RefersToLocal and voila!  All working fine.  Not sure why I didn't notice that but thanks so much for the quick response.

Comment: You should avoid using `RefersToLocal` and use `RefersTo` instead - else your code will depend on the regional settings of the computer.

Comment: OK, thank you - good tip!